# Devise: sign out certain user, NOT the scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want a user (with admin role) to be able to sign out another user after deleting his account. The problem is that [sign_out](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers%3asign_out) helper method signs out both of the users since it works with their scope, which is the same. How do I sign out only the one user?

Here is the code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    sign_out @user
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, notice: I18n.t("messages.user_destroyed")
  end
  # ...
end
```

And, as a sub-question, is it a good practice to use controllers extending devise's for similar user-related tasks i.e. adding custom methods like `index`, `show`, etc. to them?

Comment: I am having the *very* same problem. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Eduardo No, but if you need to ban a user for example you could override `active_for_authentication?` method of the user model and redirect him and it should work. Or maybe setting `current_user` to `null` will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following in your devise controller config:

```
config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. As I said, all the users relate to the same scope - `:user`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit this issue, but (for me at least) it seems it's not necessary. I'm using CanCanCan for authorisation, and if I simply delete the user without logging them out, then as soon as the user tries to do anything CanCanCan identifies that they're not an authorised user and won't let them do it. As I've got it set up, it just redirects them straight to the login page.

"Logged in as a non-existent user" turns out to be "not logged in at all".